# rsync hangs with message "name lookup failed for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: No address associated with hostname

Tags: windows, rsync

I'm trying to run an rsync daemon on windows xp.

The symptom is that when the client connects, both server and client just sit there. Nothing happens. If I wait, the client will stay connected indefinitely.

The server logs (-vvv is specified) say this:

```
2010/10/11 23:02:58 [5140] rsyncd version 3.0.7 starting, listening on port 873
2010/10/11 23:03:24 [4624] name lookup failed for 192.168.15.101: No
address associated with hostname
2010/10/11 23:03:24 [4624] connect from UNKNOWN (192.168.15.101)
```

The client output (when -vvv is specified) say this:
    opening tcp connection to eddie-desktop port 873
    sending daemon args: --server -vvvltrze.iLs --delete . "databackup/SomeDirectory/"

... and that's it.

Both machines are running windows.

Here is the conf:

```
use chroot = false
strict modes = false
hosts allow = *
log file = rsyncd.log

[databackup]
path = /cygdrive/q/databackup
read only = false
transfer logging = yes
```

server commmand:

```
C:\Program Files\ICW>"C:\Program Files\ICW\bin\rsync.exe" --config rsyncd.conf --daemon --no-detach -vvv -4
```

client command:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\DeltaCopy>rsync.exe  -v -rlt -z --chmod=a=rw,Da+x --delete "/cygdrive/E/Data/Users/Eddie/Desktop/SomeDirectory/" "eddie-desktop::databackup/SomeDirectory/"
```

Comment: as a test, I setup an rsync daemon on a different machine running mac os x, and I still got the message about the name lookup failing, but the rsync operation worked using the same client command from the same client machine as before.

Comment: It could be a firewall setting that allows TCP connection establishment packets but not subsequent TCP packets (a strange configuration, but not impossible).

Comment: all firewalls are off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rsync is performing a reverse lookup for the client's IP address and it's not matching any allowed hosts.

Posible workarounds:

- Upgrade to rsync version 3.1.0 and use the "disable reverse lookup" feature.
- Add a reverse (PTR record) for the client's IP and add it to the "hosts allow" clause on the server's `rsyncd.conf` file

Comment: Really, really old question. I marked this as the correct answer not because I verified it, but because it sounds like you know what you're talking about, and it sounds like you're probably right. Cheers.

Comment: why is it looking up client ip address?

Comment: As long as I can remember it was the default behavior for my configuration on that version of `rsync`. 
It sounds like a security feature.